# Nonexistence of digraph where all simple paths have the same cost

Tags: graph-theory

How to show that there is no strongly connected digraph $G=(V,E)$ where $E\neq\{\emptyset \}$, $|V|>2 $ with costs $c(e)\in \mathbb{R}$ for $e\in E$ such that every simple path $p$ in $G$ has the same cost $\sum\limits_{e\in p}c(e)$ and $\exists e\in E: c(e)\neq 0$

Comment: But such digraphs exist: $V=\{1,2\}$, $E=\{(1,2)\}$, $c((1,2))=1$. There is only one simple path to consider

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I updated the question to rule out these simple cases. It should be more difficult to find such digraphs now.

Comment: The path of length $0$ has cost $0$ and the path of length $1$ containing the edge $e$ has cost $c(e)\ne0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the graph is strongly connected, $|V|>2$ and $\exists e\in E:c(e)\neq 0$ there must be at least one path $p = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ of length 3 such that either subpath $\{v_1, v_2\}$, or subpath $\{v_2, v_3\}$ has different cost than $p$. Consequently, there is no graph whose paths would all have the same costs.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a strongly connected, weighted digraph such that every simple path has the same non-zero cost $c$. Also assume $E\ne\emptyset$.

Let $e\in E$ be any edge. As a single edge constitutes a path, the weight of this edge must be $c$. Then the weight of any path of length $m$ edges has weight $mc$. We conclude that there is no simple path of length $>1$.
As $E\ne\emptyset$, we can pick an edge $v_0v_1\in E$.
Let $w$ be any vertex $\ne v_1$. As $G$ is strongly connected, there must be a simple path from $v_1$ to $w$; as seen above, this path must a just the edge $v_1w$. Then the path $v_0v_1w$ cannot be simple, which implies $w=v_0$.
We conclude that $V=\{v_0,v_1\}$.

Comment: You aim at simplified case where all costs are identical. Same argument cannot be used with $c(e)\in\mathbb{R}$